# windows 7 - erase all that are registered prior to January 1st 2016

Tags: sorting

I have a lot of files  sitting in directories and sub-directories. I would like to sort them all so I can erase all that are registered prior to  January 1st 2016. How do I do that?

Comment: Go to root folder. Type `*.*` in the explorer search box. Click date column to sort results. Highlight and delete.

Comment: Make sure you have a backup first :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use "[Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/)".

I know, I know. You could script this, you could write a PowerShell script, and so on. But hey, this one also works, and it's GUI, and it's all so comfy.

**How to use it**:

- Install Everything, check options in the installer you need.
- Right-click the main folder in question, "Search with Everything"
- Here, if you don't need to filter on any file format or name, just sort ALL the result by date. (Clicking on date column.)
- Then, simply select the first - last file by holding SHIFT, and well, then delete the files. I would recommend doing a backup - just in case. The tool is reliable, but you are a human after all. I sometimes just move the files into a "to be trash" folder, just in case, instead of relying on the Recycle Bin.

Comment: Explorers got built in search though.

Comment: @JasonC: Indeed, but Explorer's search functionality is only okay for very basic tasks. Everything can wrangle hundreds of thousands of files without any hiccups even on low end hardware. It is in a completely different league. Everything is free by the way, give it a try.